# error: file ‘/boot/' not found while running ubuntu 16.04 live CD on MacBook Air (64bit) in either EFI boot mode or MBR boot mode

Tags: boot, mac, live-cd

I burned a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.04 on DVD (as well as USB) and am trying to boot a live version of Ubuntu. The system ends up eventually booting fine, but during the initial boot phase before entering grub, I get an error on my screen that reads

```
error: file ‘/boot/' not found
```

What does this error mean and imply? Why am I getting this? if the live CD can't find the boot directory, how is it still booting?

See link below for pic 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTlDZ.jpg

Comment: @mook765 I suppose I meant DVD. I will make edits. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have an answer?

Comment: Corrupted download (always verifiy the downloaded image, instructions are on the downloade page) or something went wrong when burnimg image to USB, which software did you use? There is no other way than to start over.

Comment: @mook765 I burned it from mac os. Download was verified. Burned iso with finder in mac. could it be a problem with the cd burner firmware or hardware at all?

Comment: Maybe you should try the instructions [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0).

Comment: @mook765 how does it still boot if it cant find the efi boot folder?

Comment: Did you remove MacOS and want to run only Ubuntu on this machine?

Comment: Yep. Brand new drive, never had data on it. Unless macs have an efi folder embedded inside their firmware, im not seeing how this could boot.

Comment: I think the error message comes from your firmware, it expects MacOS installed which is still the first entry in the boot order, fails to boot, and jumps to next entry in the boot order which is the Ubuntu installer. Explore your firmware settings. You save a lot of time if you mention such things in the question from the beginning.

Comment: @mook765 Aside from resetting vram at boot and changing the boot order in linux terminal, I thought mac firmware settings were relatively inaccessable. How can I manipulate firmware settings?

Comment: @mook765 ^^^^ ?

Comment: Any way to boost this post?

Comment: Edit your post and add some more details so your question will be bumped to the home-page. Another good place to ask might be https://apple.stackexchange.com/ as your question may be more related to your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Change the BIOS to Legacy first and not UEFI did it for me.

Comment: how do you do that on a mac?